g++ modules -- unable to import variables from modules
I'm not able to import variables from my module; I have 2 files test.cc and main.cc. I compile the first with g++ -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -c test.cc which works fine; when I use the same command to compile main.cc I get this error: main.cc:8:29: error: ‘INVALID’ was not declared in this scope. Here is test.cc:
export module test;
import <iostream>;

export namespace foo {
  int8_t constexpr INVALID = 0xff;
  char constexpr UNDEF = -1;
}

and here is main.cc:
import test;
import <iostream>;

using namespace std;
using namespace foo;

int main() {
  cout << "INVALID = " << INVALID << endl;
  return 0;
}

Thanks for any help. I tried adding the foo:: prefix to INVALID but it made no difference.
The full gcc error is:
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:8:29: error: ‘INVALID’ was not declared in this scope
    8 |     cout << "INVALID = " << INVALID << endl;
      |                             ^~~~~~~


You want to export the constexpr

Exporting the namespace should export everything in it I though ?

I found the fix: Adding "inline" to both declarations in test.cc fixes the problem.
